# Aplicación de Ruby no carga clases de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo las vistas para esta aplicación en Bootstrap. Este es un ejemplo:

http://mailclient-dmuldoon.c9.io/app/statistics/page_2

La primera tabla tiene las clases `table table-hover`, pero no funciona,  Bootstrap no carga correctamente.

No sé nada acerca de Ruby, ¿qué puedo hacer para arreglarlo?, ¿dónde debería revisar?

En `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` también lo tengo:

```
@import "bootstrap"; 
@import "font-awesome"; 
@import "plugins/iCheck/custom.css"; 
@import "plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.css"; 
@import "plugins/sweetalert.css"; 
@import "plugins/chosen/chosen.css"; 
@import "plugins/datepicker/datepicker.css"; 
@import "plugins/nouslider/jquery.nouislider.css";  
@import "plugins/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css"; 
@import "plugins/chartist/chartist.min.css"; 
@import "bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"; 
@import "animate"; 
@import "style"; 
@import "widuStyle";
```

Comment: revisando las hojas de estilo y tu html, no veo que llames a Bootstrap por algún lado. Si deseas ser ayudado, agrega más detalles. En lo poco que he visto, percibo que hay problemas al tener el recurso (bootstrap) en un servidor externo, trata de tenerlo en el mismo servidor y veamos qué sucede. Saludos

Comment: Bootstrap es llamado de la siguiente forma en el archivo app/assets/javascriptsapplication.js:

//= require components/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Eso solo agrega las funciones javascript, pero no las hojas de estilo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la gema de bootstrap agregada en tu gemfile? de lo contrario debe agregarlas

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Lugo de agregarlas, `bundle install` no se puede quedar, una vez instaladas las gemas, procedes a agregar las siguientes variable a `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

cambia el `application.css.scss` a `mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

Por otro lado no olvidar los require para js en `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` agregando

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Para mas información puedes visitar el [repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) en [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de usar bootstrap en Rails (Asumo que es el framework que estas usando)

- Usar la gema bootstrap, bootstrap-sass o bootstrap-less
- Colocar los js en la carpeta vendor y referenciarlos desde tu layout
- Usar bower o similar para obtener bootstrap y refierenciarlos en el layout

Segue cual de estos métodos hayas usado la respuesta podría variar, es importante considerar que como mínimo debes importar el archivo boostrap.js y los estilos boostrap.css (o variantes .min, .coffe, .less. scss )